# In SQL after joining two tables with a primary key how do I return only the rows where a value in another column differs between the tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, where-clause

I have code reading

`SELECT * FROM table1 A JOIN table2 B ON A.id = B.id WHERE_____?`

The "id"s in table 1 and 2 are the same but some of the other values in different columns may differ. How do I search every column and return only the rows where there is a difference between table 1 and 2. For values that differ will it return the row from table 1? Thank you.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You would use:

```
where a.col1 <> b.col1 or a.col2 <> b.col2 or . . .
```

or, if you need to take `NULL`s into account:

```
where not (a.col1 <=> b.col1 and a.col2 <=> b.col2 and . . . )
```

Comment: What if there are around 40 columns, could I avoid typing out all the "ands"? Is it possible the 'where' can be generic so that a similar code could be used on other databases? Thank you.

Comment: @user1063981  . . . You can generate the code using either a SQL query or a spreadsheet.